# Method is both defined and undefined in a static Linux library

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, visual-studio-2019

I'm using visual studio 2019 and compiling for ARM android.
One of the twelve libraries in my solution is failing to link properly.

It is showing a sizable number of class methods that are both defined and undefined.

Here is one example using the command line:
nm -C -g Services_Droid.a  1>Services_Droid_All.txt

I get a listing and the example constructor method shows::

E:\code\Services_Droid_All.txt (5 hits)

```
Line 834:           U hCitem::hCitem(int)
Line 1073:          U hCitem::hCitem(int)
Line 1197: 0000006c T hCitem::hCitem(int)   // there is only one definition in this file
Line 1199: 0000006c T hCitem::hCitem(int)
Line 5747:          U hCitem::hCitem(int)
```

Linking this library into my main program generates a duplicate of the three
undefined items which fails the link.

There are a large number of methods that have the same issue in this library.

Any ideas for what causes this and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure all these undefined symbols come from the same object file as the defined symbol? It is quite normal for a function to be defined in one object file and undefined in another. A library is just a collection of object files. Besides it is normal to have two versions of a symbol for constructors (the mangled names are different).

Comment: where's-my-share: Thanks. I didn't know the librarian didn't link a static library.         
   Any idea for why the undefined remain in the main dynamic library link? (ie the dynamic library links in a couple of static libraries of which this is one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is showing a sizable number of class methods that are both defined and undefined.

That is *completely normal*: an archive library is not much more than a collection of `.o` files. One of these files defines `hCitem::hCitem(int)`. A few other files reference it.

You can observe that this is in fact the case by using `nm -AC Services_Droid.a`.

> One of the twelve libraries in my solution is failing to link properly.

You should ask a separate question, explaining your *actual* problem.

Comment: Ok let's abandon this. I'll put in a linker question when I can isolate it.

Comment: @PaulWinkle You shouldn't abandon the questions you've asked. If this answer helped you, upvote it. If it completely answered the question you asked, also accept the answer.

Comment: n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. actually was first;)

Comment: @PaulWinkle Did you find why it caused linking error?